# Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I need to generate a whole bunch of vertically-stacked plots in matplotlib. The result will be saved using `savefig` and viewed on a webpage, so I don't care how tall the final image is, as long as the subplots are spaced so they don't overlap.

No matter how big I allow the figure to be, the subplots always seem to overlap.

My code currently looks like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import my_other_module

titles, x_lists, y_lists = my_other_module.get_data()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,60))
for i, y_list in enumerate(y_lists):
    plt.subplot(len(titles), 1, i)
    plt.xlabel("Some X label")
    plt.ylabel("Some Y label")
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.plot(x_lists[i],y_list)
fig.savefig('out.png', dpi=100)
```

Comment: This question also applies to `pandas.DataFrame.plot` with subplots, and to seaborn axes-level plots (those with the ax parameter): `sns.lineplot(..., ax=ax)`

Answer (score 747, accepted):

Please review [matplotlib: Tight Layout guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/tight_layout_guide.html) and try using [`matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html), or [`matplotlib.figure.Figure.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.tight_layout)

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(8, 8))
fig.tight_layout() # Or equivalently,  "plt.tight_layout()"

plt.show()
```

---

Without Tight Layout

[image]

---

With Tight Layout

[image]

Comment: So `tight_layout()` makes the layout.... _less_ tight. Interesting name.

Comment: @Harry It's short for "hold _tight_. Imma _layout_ this,"

Answer (score 527):

You can use [`plt.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) to change the spacing between the subplots.

call signature:

```
subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
```

The parameter meanings (and suggested defaults) are:

```
left  = 0.125  # the left side of the subplots of the figure
right = 0.9    # the right side of the subplots of the figure
bottom = 0.1   # the bottom of the subplots of the figure
top = 0.9      # the top of the subplots of the figure
wspace = 0.2   # the amount of width reserved for blank space between subplots
hspace = 0.2   # the amount of height reserved for white space between subplots
```

The actual defaults are controlled by the rc file

Comment: Nice! So, this works for me to increase the vertical separation between two subplots: `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)`. I call it just before `plt.show()`. Note to anyone wondering: the `0.3` is in units of _inches_ I'm pretty sure. I'm not sure how they handle different screen sizes though...

Answer (score 105):

Similar to `tight_layout` matplotlib now (as of version 2.2) provides [`constrained_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html). In contrast to `tight_layout`, which may be called any time in the code for a single optimized layout, `constrained_layout` is a property, which may be active and will optimze the layout before every drawing step.

Hence it needs to be activated before or during subplot creation, such as `figure(constrained_layout=True)` or `subplots(constrained_layout=True)`.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,4, constrained_layout=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

constrained_layout may as well be set via `rcParams`

```
plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True
```

---

See the [what's new entry](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#constrained-layout-manager) and the [Constrained Layout Guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html)

Comment: Does using constrained_layout = True squeeze the text?  I understand using tight_layout changes all sizes, such that for example the font become smaller.

Comment: In many cases, `constrained_layout` is much better than `tight_layout` if one needs the subplots to fill the window, and even better and simpler than setting `subplots_adjust` manually. (tight_layout is actually far from tight... it's rather "loose".)

Comment: @tetukowski `tight_layout` definitely does _not_ change fonts sizes.

Answer (score 95):

Using `subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` or a very small number (`hspace=0.001`) will completely remove the whitespace between the subplots, whereas `hspace=None` does not.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tic

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

x = np.arange(100)
y = 3.*np.sin(x*2.*np.pi/100.)

for i in range(1, 6):
    temp = 510 + i
    ax = plt.subplot(temp)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
    temp = tic.MaxNLocator(3)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(temp)
    ax.set_xticklabels(())
    ax.title.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

#### `hspace=0` or `hspace=0.001`

[image]

#### `hspace=None`

[image]

Comment: I believe you can move the call to `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` outside the loop and achieve the same result.

Answer (score 37):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,60))
plt.subplots_adjust( ... )
```

The **plt.subplots_adjust** method:

```
def subplots_adjust(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    call signature::

      subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None,
                      wspace=None, hspace=None)

    Tune the subplot layout via the
    :class:`matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams` mechanism.  The parameter
    meanings (and suggested defaults) are::

      left  = 0.125  # the left side of the subplots of the figure
      right = 0.9    # the right side of the subplots of the figure
      bottom = 0.1   # the bottom of the subplots of the figure
      top = 0.9      # the top of the subplots of the figure
      wspace = 0.2   # the amount of width reserved for blank space between subplots
      hspace = 0.2   # the amount of height reserved for white space between subplots

    The actual defaults are controlled by the rc file
    """
    fig = gcf()
    fig.subplots_adjust(*args, **kwargs)
    draw_if_interactive()
```

**or**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,60))
fig.subplots_adjust( ... )
```

The size of the picture matters.

"I've tried messing with hspace, but increasing it only seems to make all of the graphs smaller without resolving the overlap problem."

Thus to make more white space and keep the sub plot size the total image needs to be bigger.

Answer (score 30):

You could try the [`.subplot_tool()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_tool.html)

```
plt.subplot_tool()
```

Answer (score 9):

- Resolving this issue when plotting a dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default backend.

  - The following works for whichever `kind=` is specified (e.g. `'bar'`, `'scatter'`, `'hist'`, etc.).
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

### Example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sinusoidal sample data
sample_length = range(1, 15+1)
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
data = np.array([np.sin(t*rads) for t in sample_length])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=pd.Series(rads.tolist(), name='radians'), columns=[f'freq: {i}x' for i in sample_length])

# default plot with subplots; each column is a subplot
axes = df.plot(subplots=True)
```

[image]

### Adjust the Spacing

- Adjust the default parameters in [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

  1. Change `figsize`: a width of 5 and a height of 4 for each subplot is a good place to start.
  2. Change `layout`: (rows, columns) for the layout of subplots.
  3. `sharey=True` and `sharex=True` so space isn't taken for redundant labels on each subplot.
- The `.plot` method returns a numpy array of [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes), which should be flattened to easily work with.
- Use `.get_figure()` to extract the `DataFrame.plot` figure object from one of the `Axes`.
- Use `fig.tight_layout()` if desired.

```py
axes = df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(3, 5), figsize=(25, 16), sharex=True, sharey=True)

# flatten the axes array to easily access any subplot
axes = axes.flat

# extract the figure object
fig = axes[0].get_figure()

# use tight_layout
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

#### `df`

```
# display(df.head(3))
         freq: 1x  freq: 2x  freq: 3x  freq: 4x  freq: 5x  freq: 6x  freq: 7x  freq: 8x  freq: 9x  freq: 10x  freq: 11x  freq: 12x  freq: 13x  freq: 14x  freq: 15x
radians                                                                                                                                                            
0.00     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0.01     0.010000  0.019999  0.029996  0.039989  0.049979  0.059964  0.069943  0.079915  0.089879   0.099833   0.109778   0.119712   0.129634   0.139543   0.149438
0.02     0.019999  0.039989  0.059964  0.079915  0.099833  0.119712  0.139543  0.159318  0.179030   0.198669   0.218230   0.237703   0.257081   0.276356   0.295520
```

Answer (score 5):

- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827848/7758804) shows using `fig.tight_layout` after creating the figure. However, `tight_layout` can be set when creating the figure, because [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) accepts additional parameters with `**fig_kw`. ***All additional keyword arguments are passed to the [`pyplot.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) call***.
- See [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804) for accessing and plotting in subplots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the figure with tight_layout=True
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If passing
`tight_layout=True` to `plt.subplots()`
or
`fig.tight_layout()`
is not adding sufficient spacing between subplots,
consider tuning with pad like `tight_layout(pad=2.0)` to get desired spacing.

Comment: This works 100%. The underdog 