# Python subplots fixed spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a 4x3 subplots grid and I would like to have fixed spacing between them.
I am using subplots_adjust, see below. However, the figures are arranged uniformly within the overall window and do not have fixed spaces. Thanks for your advice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 3)

axes[0, 0].imshow(data)
axes[1, 0].imshow(data)
axes[2, 0].imshow(data)
axes[3, 0].imshow(data)

axes[0, 1].imshow(data)
axes[1, 1].imshow(data)
axes[2, 1].imshow(data)
axes[3, 1].imshow(data)

axes[0, 2].imshow(data)
axes[1, 2].imshow(data)
axes[2, 2].imshow(data)
axes[3, 2].imshow(data)

plt.setp(axes, xticks=[], yticks=[])

plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=.05, hspace=.05)

plt.show()
```

([Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6541123/2926577) solves overlapping labels, this question specifically relates to constant spacing between subplots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you face, is that the arguments of `subplots_adjust` are relative values, i.e. fractions of the figure width and height, see [docu](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams), and not absolute values.

You are plotting 4 rows and 3 columns of squares (10x10) in the "default canvas" (might be 8x6). 
However, the figure size is defined in width times height, hence columns times rows.
So you have to swap rows and columns and change your *subplots* call to

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4)
```

and your spaces will be equal. If not, try adding `figsize=(8,6)` to set the figure size.
Of course, you have the adjust the indices of the *imshow* lines.
[image]

As an alternative, you could swap the *figsize* arguments.

Comment: thanks, that helped. But I still have to play with figsize to adjust the spacing b/w the figs.

Comment: For future, please leave code and not a snapshot so that people can quickly test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can control the spacing and position of each subplot directly using [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpecBase). There's more information [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html). Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

plt.figure(figsize = (6,6)) # set the figure size to be square

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 3)
# set the space between subplots and the position of the subplots in the figure
gs.update(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.4, left = 0.1, right = 0.7, bottom = 0.1, top = 0.9) 


for g in gs:
    ax = plt.subplot(g)
    plt.imshow(data)

plt.show()
```

[image: gridspec example]