# Grid of images in matplotlib with no padding

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a grid of images in matplotlib using gridspec. The problem is, I can't seem to get it to get rid of the padding between the rows.

[image]

Here's my attempt at the solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os import chdir
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

chdir('/home/matthew/Dropbox/Work/writing/'+
    'paper_preperation/jump_figs')
files = listdir('/home/matthew/Dropbox/Work/writing/'+
    'paper_preperation/jump_figs')

images = [Image.open(f) for f in files]


"""
fig = plt.figure()

grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, # similar to subplot(111)
                nrows_ncols = (2, 5), # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                axes_pad=0.1, # pad between axes in inch.
                )
"""

num_rows = 2
num_cols = 5

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(num_rows, num_cols, wspace=0.0)

ax = [plt.subplot(gs[i]) for i in range(num_rows*num_cols)]
gs.update(hspace=0)
#gs.tight_layout(fig, h_pad=0,w_pad=0)

for i,im in enumerate(images):
    ax[i].imshow(im)
    ax[i].axis('off')
    #ax_grid[i/num_cols,i-(i/num_cols)*num_cols].imshow(im) # The AxesGrid object work as a list of axes.
    #ax_grid[i/num_cols,i-(i/num_cols)*num_cols].axis('off')

"""
all_axes = fig.get_axes()
for ax in all_axes:
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)
    if ax.is_first_row():
        ax.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
    if ax.is_last_row():
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
    if ax.is_first_col():
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(True)
    if ax.is_last_col():
        ax.spines['right'].set_visible(True)
"""
plt.show()
```

Also does anyone know how to make each subplot bigger?

Comment: Does [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) help? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6541123/1643946

Comment: What you're seeing is a limitation of the way matplotlib defines subplot positions Because `imshow` will force the aspect of each figure to be 1 (and therefore square), the definition of subplot locations will result in with gaps even when `hspace=0, wspace=0`. I don't have time to elaborate right now, but to fix this you actually need to calculate what `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` should be at each figure resize event.   Alternately, just use `imshow(..., aspect='auto')`, but you'll have non-square pixels.

Comment: Works great!  I used `fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)` to render at higher resolution.

Answer (score 11):

For me a combination of `aspect="auto"` and `subplots_adjust` worked. Also I always try to make the subplots quadratic. For the individual subplot size `figsize` can be adjusted.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=max_rows, ncols=max_cols, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, image in enumerate(images):
    row = idx // max_cols
    col = idx % max_cols
    axes[row, col].axis("off")
    axes[row, col].imshow(image, cmap="gray", aspect="auto")
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.05, hspace=.05)
plt.show()
```