# Reshaping pyplot subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code:

```
def plot_yz_over_x_elementwise(zarray):
    for i in range(zarray.shape[1]):
        for j in range(zarray.shape[2]):
            plt.subplot2grid((zarray.shape[1],zarray.shape[2]),(i,j))
            plt.plot(zarray[:,i,j])
            frame = plt.gca()
            frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
            frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([1,0.5,0])
```

Which takes a 3D np array and plots it in a figure like this:

[image]

Which is embedded in an ipython notebook.  What I need is some way to format this graph so that the axis labels aren't on top of each other.  I guess that means either spreading it out on the notebook...or shrinking it within each cell in python.  How do I do one or the other to get this plot looking right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tight_layout](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) might be what you're looking for

```
def plot_yz_over_x_elementwise(zarray):
    for i in range(zarray.shape[1]):
        for j in range(zarray.shape[2]):
            plt.subplot2grid((zarray.shape[1],zarray.shape[2]),(i,j))
            plt.plot(zarray[:,i,j])
            frame = plt.gca()
            frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
            frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([1,0.5,0])
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Bottomline the answer is to use  [plt.tight_layout](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)

Comment: Hey, there is virtue to having alternative search titles.  I definitely searched for this, and found nothing.  Presumably, if I were an expert, I would have found those links...but if I were an expert, I wouldn't have a question.  In other words, thanks for pointing that out...but I'd never have found those search lines.