# Bottom graph is overlapping top graph's label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, overlap

What's the problem? The label of top graph is under bottom graph... I really can't imagine how to fix this. I thought it will work standardly.

The code bellow is from site http://www.physics.nyu.edu/pine/pymanual/html/chap5/chap5_plot.html#basic-plotting.

The image of how the graph must be is in the link http://www.physics.nyu.edu/pine/pymanual/html/_images/subplotDemo.png.

The image of my graph obtained by copying the code from the site above is in the link [My overlapped graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3YVs.png).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0.01, 8., 0.04)
y = np.sqrt((8./theta)**2-1.)
ytan = np.tan(theta)
ytan = np.ma.masked_where(np.abs(ytan)>20., ytan)
ycot = 1./np.tan(theta)
ycot = np.ma.masked_where(np.abs(ycot)>20., ycot)

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(theta, y)
plt.plot(theta, ytan)
plt.ylim(-8, 8)
plt.axhline(color="gray", zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=np.pi/2., color="gray", linestyle='--', zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=3.*np.pi/2., color="gray", linestyle='--', zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=5.*np.pi/2., color="gray", linestyle='--', zorder=-1)
plt.xlabel("theta")
plt.ylabel("tan(theta)")

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(theta, -y)
plt.plot(theta, ycot)
plt.ylim(-8, 8)
plt.axhline(color="gray", zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=np.pi, color="gray", linestyle='--', zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=2.*np.pi, color="gray", linestyle='--', zorder=-1)
plt.xlabel("theta")
plt.ylabel("cot(theta)")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty simple solution: Insert the line `plt.tight_layout()` before you are showing your graph. This line will automatically adjust margins between subplots so everything looks great.

In your code it would look like this:

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

More information about the `tight_layout` can be found here: [Tight Layout Guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know other solutions?

Comment: Yeah you could use `subplots_adjust` to customize the spacing more specifically. Here is some more information: [sublots_adjust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6541454/7846567)