# Titles Over lapping on Large Subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Overlapping subplot figures

[image]

Relevant Code

```
plt2287 = fig.add_subplot(661)
plt2287.plot(X_wavelength, y_2287)
plt2287.title.set_text(' 2287 ')

plt2092 = fig.add_subplot(662)
plt2092.plot(X_wavelength, y_2092)
plt2092.title.set_text(' 2092 ')

plt2287 = fig.add_subplot(661)
plt2287.plot(X_wavelength, y_2287)
plt2287.title.set_text(' 2287 ')

plt2092 = fig.add_subplot(662)
plt2092.plot(X_wavelength, y_2092)
plt2092.title.set_text(' 2092 ')

plt2146 = fig.add_subplot(667)
plt2146.plot(X_wavelength, y_2146)
plt2146.title.set_text(' 2146 ')

plt2424 = fig.add_subplot(668)
plt2424.plot(X_wavelength, y_2424)
plt2424.set_title(' 2424 ')

plt.show()
```

Is there something specific I'm missing? Why does this happen?

Different to [adjusting subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib) because I can't keep readjusting the values constantly. With over 32 Subplots it becomes very difficult. Also, why does this even happen? I tried using `.set_title` and `'title.set_text`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @l'L'l interesting, I have over 32 subplots so doing this per subplot would be a huge undertaking

Comment: Did you try this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827848/499581 (`plt.tight_layout`)?

Comment: @I'LI Nice, very cool! [Too wide now ](https://imgur.com/TY6HEv3)

Comment: You can adjust the spacing like this `plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)`... just play with the numbers until you get something more desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xming as a backend bc of Windows Linux Subsystem.

Click the adjustment button at the top

[image]

And Click Tight layout, it auto formats everything!

S/O to @I'L'I provided some great & cool new tools for me to use!