# I am not able to change the distance between to subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am pretty new to python, and I am plotting two `imshow` objects into a figure, one below the other. However, I am not able to change the horizontal distance between the two objects, i.e. they are too far apart.

As suggested in [Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib), I have tried using `plt.tight_layout()` and `plt.subplots_adjust`, but it didn't affect the plot at all.

This is how I created the plot (I left out the parts where I define the arrays to be plotted and the properties of the `imshow` plot):

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.imshow(help_vector, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.imshow(plot_vector, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

I dont't know if this is important, but both subplots have a title, the whole figure has a title, and the second subplot has a 'legend' next to it which I created by using the follwing code:

```py
patches = [mpatches.Patch(color='lime', label = 'No relevant error'), mpatches.Patch(color='yellow',label='Medium error'), mpatches.Patch(color='orange',label='Large error'), mpatches.Patch(color='red',
    label='Unacceptable')]
    plt.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0)
```

When storing the image with `savefig`, I added the argument `bbox_inches='tight'`.

[Image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lg9w.png)

Any kind of help is very much appreciated!

Edit: Added an image of the plot.

Comment: Could you please provide the resulting plots, so we can see what do you mean by "too far apart"?

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust` *will* work. You need to play with the `top` and `bottom` parameters.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It worked! Thank you very much! I was only using the `hspace` parameter and therefore it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out, the solution was to use the `top` and `bottom` parameters of `subplots_adjust()`. In my case, `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.7,bottom=0.3)` was what I needed.