# Adjust matplotlib grid settings via subplot instead of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to achieve equivalent settings to the `subplots` `grid` adjustments but using the individual `subplot` API's?

In particular the `subplots` may be adjusted via the `GridSpec`:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1, height_ratios=[2, 2, 1, 1])
```

The `subplots` may also be adjusted via `gridspec_kw`:

```
gridspec_kw={'wspace':0,'hspace':0})
```

Or even:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=2)
```

However I was not able to find a similar capability directly on the `subplot` api - e.g. following is *not* valid:

```
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1, gridspec_kw={'wspace':0,'hspace':0})
```

The rationale for finding this is I am working with pre-existing code that only uses `subplot`.  It would be a meaningful effort to convert the code to `subplots` and so a direct addition of just the grid capability would be preferred if possible.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827668/4932316) answer which works at `subplot` level?

Comment: yea that's good: can you make an answer. btw how did you sniff out those `subplot` specific API's from matplotlib?

Comment: I would rather close it as a dupe ;) since the dupe has many more alternatives. I hope you agree with me

Comment: fair enough: but would you have some comment on how to "find" these offbeat api's on `matplotlib.pyplot`.  I can't seem to get head around how to discover what's available.

Comment: [This](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/index.html) contains it all

Comment: ok that's helpful . thx!