# How to I space out the histograms in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, data-science, histogram

I'm sure there is a quick fix for this. How do I make it so the column titles (histogram titles in image) don't get overlapped by the histogram above it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
class_train.hist(bins=50, figsize=(12,7))
plt.show()
```

[image: code histogram output]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots-in-matplotlib

Comment: [plt.tight_layout](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, really quite simple: change the figsize :S

so changing it to 15,15 makes the plot much more readable:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
class_train.hist(bins=50, figsize=(15,15))
plt.show()
```

[image: new histograms]