# Histograms overlap with .hist function

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram for all the columns in a table. When I do that, they all overlap and I can't read any of them. I have tried to change fig size, but I would just like them to display neatly /legibly. Is there a way to do this with over 80 columns?

If not, can you recommend a better way to do all 80+ histograms? Thanks in advance!

```
df.hist(figsize = (15, 10))
```

Here is what it looks like on my side[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgRWQ.png)

Comment: increase `figsize` and or change the `layout=` parameter.  (1) `ax = df.hist(figsize=(28, 20), layout=(7, 4), sharey=True, sharex=True)` (2) `axes = axes.flat` (3) `fig = axes[0].get_figure()` (4) `fig.tight_layout()`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70137133/7758804) of the duplicate.

Comment: with 80 subplots it might be better to plot the columns in groups of 20, with a layout of (4, 5) or (5, 4). Select groups of columns with `.iloc`: `df.iloc[:, 0:20].plot(kind='hist',...)`, `df.iloc[:, 20:40].plot(kind='hist',...)`, ...

Comment: TrentonMcKinney thank you! I will do that instead.