# Python adjust space between 2 line of subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I reduce the space between 2 line of subplot ?

[image]

I tried `Tight_Layout()` But it also reduce space between columns

Below is my subplot structure :

```
ChartMatrix, ((A,B,C),(D,E,F)) = plt.subplots(2,3)
```

Comment: Try `plt.subplots(2, 3, constrained_layout=True)`. Not sure if it'll help, and it's still technically experimental, but usually the best manager

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you but didn't change the space between :/

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6541454/3281097) help?