# How to place the suptitle rotated on the side of the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, figure

I'm working with Matplotlib in Python, and have the simple figure-suptitle layout shown below

```
  Title
----------
|Figure  |
|Pieces  |
----------
```

The figure pieces are squished a bit, however. To make room, I would like to put the figure suptitle on the side, like so

```
----------   
|Figure  | (title rotated 90 degrees) 
|Pieces  |
----------
```

The reason I would like to do this is that there are 47 of these, and each will go on its own 8.5" x 11" page. An alternative would be to rotate the figure itself, although I imagine that might be harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `rotation` parameter.
- See [`matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) &  [`matplotlib.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) for available parameters.

  - This works for the explicit `Axes` interface, and for the implicit `pyplot` interface.
- This answer also works for `seaborn` [axes-level plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions).
- Also see [Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6541123/7758804).
- **Tested in `python 3.10` and `matplotlib 3.5.2`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = ['group_a', 'group_b', 'group_c']
values = [1, 10, 100]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(3, 9))

ax[0].bar(names, values)
ax[1].scatter(names, values)
ax[2].plot(names, values)
fig.suptitle('Categorical Plotting', ha='right', va='center', x=1.1, y=0.5, rotation=270)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
names = ['group_a', 'group_b', 'group_c']
values = [1, 10, 100]

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))

plt.subplot(131)
plt.bar(names, values)
plt.subplot(132)
plt.scatter(names, values)
plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(names, values)
plt.suptitle('Categorical Plotting', ha='right', va='center', x=0.95, y=0.5, rotation=270)
plt.show()
```

[image]