# Automatic adjustment of a subplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am implementing an algorithme with Python and I would like to plot 2 subplots.

This is what I obtain:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to automaticaly adjust the space between the two plots to see the title & the xlabel?

Thanks

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()`

Comment: In this case you might also want to use `sharex=True` (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improve subplot size/spacing with many subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541123/improve-subplot-size-spacing-with-many-subplots)

Comment: See in particular the comment about constrained_layout (tight layout is mildly discouraged) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51657238/3394386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `plt.tight_layout`:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
ax1.plot(arr.real)
ax1.set_title('Real part at the output of the filter')
ax2.plot(arr.imag)
ax2.set_title('Imaginary part at the output of the filter')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

With `plt.tight_layout`:

[image]

Without `plt.tight_layout`:

[image]